# Toggle GPS Programmatically Android 4.4

Tags: android, gps, root

I know. Don't do this. I don't care. It's for a root app.

The app is installed to `/system/app/` with `0777` permission

I was previously using:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
Settings.Secure.setLocationProviderEnabled(cr, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, !isGpsOn);
```

This is how I'm trying it on 4.4 since that was deprecated:

```
int value;
if (isGpsOn)value = Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;
        else value = Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY;
Settings.Secure.putInt(cr, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, value);
```

And it is silently failing (according to some user reports). How can I properly toggle GPS with Android 4.4 from an app in System folder?

Comment: I like your intro. It's got attitude. The good kind.

Comment: You can't. That's why it silently fail.

Comment: @ChuongPham, I can't accept that because system apps are able to toggle GPS (i.e. Settings). There must be a way to get my app to operate the same way as a system app. (I also don't have a 4.4 device to test on, or I may have figured it out).

Comment: Unless you know how to sign your app with an Android platform key and you obey the Privacy laws in your country, or the countries you intended to sell your app to, then toggling GPS via your app is not a viable option. Since Google just updated its Developer Policy, your requirement seemed even less favourable...

Comment: Tasker and Power Toggles are able to do this with root alone, no need for a system app. Anyone know how they are able to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Don't do this. :)

Check the code for [GPS TOGGLER](https://github.com/sms2000/GPSToggler)

> GPS toggle widget for Android rooted devices. It wrks well even for
>   those ROMs and kernels, other software failed.

With your code, just checking:
Hope you declared the following **permissions in your manifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

I had used this on rooted LG Optimus, android 4.0/4.1.
Reportedly this may no longer work but i am not sure about it for all devices and o.s.:

Switch it ON/OFF with a flag check and this code:

```
try {  
  Settings.Secure.putString (context.getContentResolver(),  
  Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED, String.format ("%s,%s",  
  Settings.Secure.getString (context.getContentResolver(),  
  Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED), LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));  
        } catch(Exception e) {}
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test, but it seems promising. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Tasker and Power Toggles are able to do this with root alone, no need for a system app. Anyone know how they are able to achieve this?